# JBoss 5.1.0 Error with EAR

Tags: ejb, jboss5.x

I am Currently trying to deploy a 4.2.3 project that I have tried to convert to 5.1 EAP. I have knocked out alot of the errors that I was getting, now I am stuck. Here are the errors that I am receiving.

```
3:22:29,893 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080
13:22:29,909 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009
13:22:29,909 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_0     date=201009150028)] Started in 20s:500ms
13:23:08,112 WARN  [HDScanner] Failed to add deployment: vfsfile:/C:/Work/JBossWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_EAP_5.x_Runtime_Server1311868948384/deploy/TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear/
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Exception determining structure: AbstractVFSDeployment(TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:85)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1001)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:437)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:387)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:297)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.addDeployment(MainDeployerAdapter.java:86)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:385)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error determining structure: TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear
at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.determineStructure(EARStructure.java:307)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:196)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:221)
at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77)
... 16 more
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: Failed to resolve schema nsURI=http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee location=http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd
at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:203)
at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:183)
at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:161)
at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.determineStructure(EARStructure.java:162)
... 20 more
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: Failed to resolve schema nsURI=http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee location=http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd
at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.SundayContentHandler.startElement(SundayContentHandler.java:281)
at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser$DelegatingContentHandler.startElement(SaxJBossXBParser.java:401)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:199)
... 23 more
13:23:09,502 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@7186353{vfszip:/C:/Work/JBossWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins    /org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_EAP_5.x_Runtime_Server1311868948384/deploy/jboss-seam.jar.jar/}
13:23:09,502 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@7186353{vfszip:/C:/Work/JBossWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_EAP_5.x_Runtime_Server1311868948384/deploy/jboss-seam.jar.jar/}
13:23:09,502 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@7186353{vfszip:/C:/Work/JBossWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_EAP_5.x_Runtime_Server1311868948384/deploy/jboss-seam.jar.jar/}
13:23:09,502 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@7186353{vfszip:/C:/Work/JBossWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_EAP_5.x_Runtime_Server1311868948384/deploy/jboss-seam.jar.jar/}
13:23:11,440 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Created KernelDeployment for: jboss-seam.jar.jar
13:23:11,440 INFO  [JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:jar=jboss-seam.jar.jar,name=TimerServiceDispatcher,service=EJB3
13:23:11,440 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   with dependencies:
13:23:11,440 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and demands:
13:23:11,440 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService
13:23:11,440 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and supplies:
13:23:11,440 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  Class:org.jboss.seam.async.LocalTimerServiceDispatcher
13:23:11,440 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:TimerServiceDispatcher/local-org.jboss.seam.async.LocalTimerServiceDispatcher
13:23:11,440 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:TimerServiceDispatcher/remote
13:23:11,456 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:TimerServiceDispatcher/local
13:23:11,456 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:jar=jboss-seam.jar.jar,name=TimerServiceDispatcher,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: jboss-seam.jar.jar
13:23:11,456 INFO  [JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:jar=jboss-seam.jar.jar,name=EjbSynchronizations,service=EJB3
13:23:11,456 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   with dependencies:
13:23:11,456 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and demands:
13:23:11,456 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService
13:23:11,456 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and supplies:
13:23:11,456 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:EjbSynchronizations/local
13:23:11,456 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:EjbSynchronizations/remote
13:23:11,456 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:EjbSynchronizations/local-org.jboss.seam.transaction.LocalEjbSynchronizations
13:23:11,456 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  Class:org.jboss.seam.transaction.LocalEjbSynchronizations
13:23:11,456 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:jar=jboss-seam.jar.jar,name=EjbSynchronizations,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: jboss-seam.jar.jar
13:23:11,659 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:jar=jboss-seam.jar.jar,name=TimerServiceDispatcher,service=EJB3
13:23:11,659 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: org.jboss.seam.async.TimerServiceDispatcher ejbName: TimerServiceDispatcher
13:23:11,815 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

    TimerServiceDispatcher/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
    TimerServiceDispatcher/local-org.jboss.seam.async.LocalTimerServiceDispatcher - EJB3.x Local Business Interface

13:23:12,034 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:jar=jboss-seam.jar.jar,name=EjbSynchronizations,service=EJB3
13:23:12,034 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: org.jboss.seam.transaction.EjbSynchronizations ejbName: EjbSynchronizations
13:23:12,065 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

    EjbSynchronizations/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
    EjbSynchronizations/local-org.jboss.seam.transaction.LocalEjbSynchronizations - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK EAP 5.1 only supports Java EE 5 while your TagTestAndCleanUp-ear.ear seems to reference a Java EE 6 schema.